# Increase mouse speed in Linux Mint beyond its default maximum?

Tags: cinnamon

So I've tried Googling this, but all I see is a lot of questions about how to slow down the mouse speed.

I'm accustomed to my mouse moving quite a bit faster than the fastest setting on Mint. Is there any way to increase the speed further, particularly without decreasing accuracy? The DE is Cinnamon, by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

My related AskUbuntu answer: https://askubuntu.com/q/27862/6016

The `xset` command allows you to change quite a few aspects of your desktop, including mouse acceleration.

```
xset m 2 1
```

The first number is the acceleration, the second is threshold. So, in the example I provided, the mouse will go 2X as fast once it's traveled 1px across the screen. Zero has some special connotations, so I'd stick with 1.

I wouldn't think you would need to set the acceleration too high to get what you're looking for.

This effect will disappear once you reboot/restart. If it works for you, the command can be added to your "Startup Applications" to be applied automatically.

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'd vote you up but apparently I need reputation for that.

Answer (score 1):

The current answer doesn't appear to work in Linux Mint 18. Instead you can use `xinput` as follows:

Determine `id` of the input device that you want to change:

```
user@computer:~$ xinput --list --short

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3071:00 06CB:82F1 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I want to change the SYNA3071:00 Touchpad, so the `id` that I'm changing is `10`.

Determine which properties you can change for this input device:

```
user@computer:~$ xinput --list-props 8

<pre>Device &apos;SYNA3071:00 06CB:82F1 Touchpad&apos;:
    Device Enabled (144):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (146): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (281): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (282): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (283):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (284):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (285):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (287):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (288):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (289):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (290):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (291):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (292):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (296): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (297):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (298):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (299):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (300):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (301): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (302): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (303): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (304): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (266): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (267):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (268):    0, 0
    Device Node (269):  &quot;/dev/input/event17&quot;
    Device Product ID (270):    1739, 33521
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (305):   &lt;no items&gt;
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (306):   0</pre>
```

I want to change the `libinput Accel Speed`, which is property `301`.

Update the `id` with a new `property` `value`:

```
user@computer:~$ xinput --set-prop 10 301 0.75
```

You can experiment with all of these properties to see which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a less technical solution to my mouse cursor moving too slow, even with maxed out sliders - I solved the issue by hooking up a different (not new but a couple of years less old) mouse to the computer.
Quadrupled (no factual measurement. Just feeling good now.) cursor speed and responsiveness without messing with xinput ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Mint settings GUI and `libinput Accel Speed` in xinput set the acceleration of the pointer, not speed. To change pointer speed, you need to set the "Coordinate Transformation Matrix", as shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358019/128880

In my case, the command is:

```
xinput --set-prop 8 158 1.600000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.600000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```